# Jenkins CI Service not working in GitLab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I know there are many posts regarding Jenkins CI in GitLab, but I am getting a weird error.

I am trying to trigger build in Jenkins when there is a push to GitLab. As following the http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html document, what I finally get is:

- Jenkins CI Service: Test settings gives me "We tried to send a request to the provided URL but an error occurred: execution expired". Dev tool Network got 302 and 200 only, no bad request nor anything bad.
- Jenkins CI (deprecated) Service: Test settings is fine, saying "We sent a request to the provided URL", but no build triggered.
- When I push to GitLab, nothing is triggered.

As the GitLab document is poorly updated, I find it confusing about this integration. Anyone experienced a successful Jenkins - GitLab integration, please help me out, would highly appreciate any specific instruction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no one ever did this recently???